# Codemirror editor is not loading content of the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I'm trying to apply **CodeMirror** to this mini web app that I'm using. It has two has 2 textareas. I'd like to add CM for better visibility, so I can edit some stuff on the get to go. So far, I managed to apply the Eclipse theme, but the tool doesn't work anymore. It seems like **CodeMirror** is not copying the content to the textarea.

When I remove the `Codemirror js` the tool works again.

Here's my 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v5qxtev/18/)

HTML

```
<textarea id="input" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
<textarea id="output" rows="10" cols="80" readonly></textarea>
```

JS

```
$('textarea').each(function(index, elem) {
  CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elem, {
    lineWrapping: true,
    mode: "javascript",
    theme: "eclipse",
    lineNumbers: true,

  });

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by *CodeMirror is not copying the content to the textarea*

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have appropriate code to copy the contents to different textarea. Please add the code.

Comment: Can you please explain your issue clearly?

Comment: Mr. Alien It's basically a javascript compressor. So when I paste the uncompressed javascript code on the first textarea and click "pack" the generated compressed javascript goes to the second area. It works fine without the CodeMirror editor, but when I apply the CodeMirror syntax highlighter, the tool doesn't work anymore. So I'm thinking that the CodeMirror editor itself doesn't have the same content as the original textarea that's why it's not generating the compressed javascript.

Comment: @VianneYuZhèng did you have a look at the browser console? You're importing a `codemirror.j`file and I guess you haven't initialized a `packer`. [This snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/lucifer63/jBYRu/) has an example of creating a `packer`. See if it helps.

Comment: @31piy isn't CodeMirror only supposed to "style" the textarea? So in theory whatever the content of the textarea should reflect as well in codemirror editor?

Comment: @Arun Kumar Thanks for the response. Good eye however that doesn't seem to be the case. The packers work fines. You can test by temporarily removing the CodeMirror script. It only doesn't work when I apply the syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is in `http://dean.edwards.name/packer/bindings.js`, exactly, at the following code:

```
"#pack-script": {
    disabled: false,

    onclick: function() {
        try {
            output.value = "";
            if (input.value) {
                var value = packer.pack(input.value, base62.checked, shrink.checked);
                output.value = value;
                message.update();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            message.error("error packing script", error);
        } finally {
            saveScript.disabled = !output.value;
            decodeScript.disabled = !output.value || !base62.checked;
        }
    }
},
```

CodeMirror uses internal formatting, and applies custom styling to the textareas. So, the direct methods for the textarea, such as `input.value` won't work. You will need to tweak it so that it uses CodeMirror's methods to get/set the values as described in [this guide](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_content) under **Content manipulation methods** section.

**Edit 1:**

Apart from correcting some syntax errors, I got that working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0v5qxtev/25/).

Changes done:

1. Returned the CodeMirror object from the `editor` function, so that it can be assigned to a variable.
2. Changed the `onclick` method. In `finally` block, there are undefined references to `saveScript`, and `decodeScript`, which I commented. And used CodeMirror's `getValue()`, and `setValue()` methods to get/set values respectively.

There still are some errors in the console, if observed, but that doesn't hamper the functionality of packer.

Comment: This must be it. If it's not too much to ask, can you guide me on how to do this? I've added bindings.js in the fiddle so we can edit it http://jsfiddle.net/0v5qxtev/24/

Comment: You're awesome! I also managed to add all the other features of the packer thanks to your detailed explanation. Thank you so much.